# Masked Text Box does not allow paste when masked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am having some issues with a Masked Text Box, and I really can't seem to isolate what the issue might be.

Whenever the mask is active, I do not have the ability to paste into said box. I remove the mask, and I do - that's the only change I make. I can't seem to figure out what it is. The box itself has no validation control (a validation script does run at a push of a button, but it is manual, and not tied to the control events)

```
// txtClaimNum
        // 
        this.txtClaimNum.AllowDrop = true;
        this.txtClaimNum.CausesValidation = false;
        this.txtClaimNum.HideSelection = false;
        this.txtClaimNum.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 83);
        this.txtClaimNum.Mask = "################-##";
        this.txtClaimNum.Name = "txtClaimNum";
        this.txtClaimNum.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 20);
        this.txtClaimNum.TabIndex = 1;
```

To activate the form on which this Text box resides, I use the following from a main form:

```
public static void ThreadProcAddClaim()
    {
        Application.Run(new AddClaim());            
    }
```

That being said, I don't have any code I know of on that form that would be supressing this either. I did some searches, but most people seem to want to supress the paste or copy functions. I need them active. Anyone have any suggestions for an idjit? Let me know if you need any further information as well.

Thanks

Comment: This mask allows just numbers; so I understand that you are trying to paste just numbers in, don't you?

Comment: Correct. I try to paste in a 16 digit number, followed by a -, and two more numbers. If I attempt to paste in an 18 digit number, or the 16-2, either way, it does not paste. The Paste option does appear in the context menu, but does nothing when selected, and Ctrl V does nothing either.

Comment: This does not make any sense. If you open a new project in VS 2010, put a masked textbox on it with your code (the property change part), it would work fine. If you try to paste numbers + non-supported characters (e.g., a letter), the numbers would be pasted and the non-supported characters would be ignored. The paste option would always be there when right-clicking on the control, unless having ReadOnly set to true (or similar). Not sure what is happening in your project but with the information/code you provide, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: *sigh* I figured that might be the case. I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: You have to provide more information. If you don't have it, you should remove potential sources of problems (by starting a new project from scratch, for example). I am not saying that your problem cannot be solved, but not with the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You made me realize I was looking in the wrong area.

Comment: You are welcome. This is what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I went back through, and I am really an idiot.

```
Thread a = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcAddClaim));
         a.Name = "AddClaim";
        a.Start();
```

I did not have the Apartment State set. I just set it, and it worked perfectly.

```
Thread a = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcAddClaim));
        a.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        a.Name = "AddClaim";
        a.Start();
```